# VBA Looping through range to addshape in referenced cells

Tags: excel, vba

What I'm basically trying to do is build up a Gantt chart in Excel: each column represents a week. Now I want to add in milestones and this I would like to do by adding a small dot (shape) in the center of the week the milestone is to be delivered. In my data I have one column (X) that specifies in which cells I need a shape placed; this is different for each row. The screenshot should clarify what I mean. I can do it for one line, but I'm having issues with building the loop that runs down from cell X11 to X20. Not sure if it's important, but I do not need a milestone in every line; for some lines the cell in column X is empty.

[image: screenshot]

Now what I have is the following, but this returns an error. I have no idea why or how to fix this.

```
Sub Bolletjes()

Const BallSize = 8
Const FirstColumnKV = "X"
Const FirstRowKV = 11

Dim clLeft As Double
Dim clTop As Double
Dim clWidth As Double
Dim clHeight As Double

Dim findcellKV As Variant

Dim cl As Range
Dim shpOval As Shape
Dim Counter As Integer

For Counter = FirstRowKV To 20
findcellKV = Range(FirstColumnKV & Counter).Value
Set cl = Range(findcellKV)

clLeft = cl.Left
clTop = cl.Top
clOffsetV = cl.Height / 2 - BallSize / 2
clOffsetH = cl.Width / 2 - BallSize / 2

Set shpOval = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, clLeft + clOffsetH,clTop + clOffsetV, BallSize, BallSize)
shpOval.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(152, 52, 7)
shpOval.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(152, 52, 7)
shpOval.Line.Weight = 1

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Why people still using excel for what it is not done ? Use a project manager app with Gantt view, there are thousand, some free other not. Don't reinvent wheel when their are a lot of solution.

Comment: Where do you see the error?

Comment: Actually I'm pulling the data for this Gantt from a project management platform. But it's not able to provide me with the views I need, hence why I'm building them in Excel.

@Sean: when I run the code I get "Run-time error '1004' Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed"

Comment: It has to be `Range(Counter, FirstColumnKV)` with 'X' being `1`. If you want to use letters (don't do that) you would have to use `Range("X" & Counter)`.

Comment: @Tom, your second solution works, although I still get the run-time error, though I suspect that's because of the blank cells in column X (it works for the first two rows). 

The first solution does not seem to work. What do you mean by "with 'X' being 1"? Suppose I avoid using letters, X would become 24, right? How could I alter the code for that to work?

Comment: Working on an answer.

Comment: In any case I got the run-time error out of the way. Added in an if statement in between the For Next and that solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this seems to be too long for a comment, so I'll just put this as an answer.

First of all, constants ( `Const`-keyword ) are used if you don't want to change their value *at all*. So for your purpose you should define them as variables, preferably as `Long`.

Second, IMO the use of index letters in VBA-code is not very smooth. Try to use index numbers for referencing to cells or columns. You can add, multiply and do lots of other fun stuff, that you just can't with index letters.

As for your code:

```
Sub Bolletjes()

Dim ws as Worksheet

Dim clLeft As Double
Dim clTop As Double
Dim clWidth As Double
Dim clHeight As Double

Dim BallSize As Long
Dim FirstColumnKV As Long
Dim FirstRowKV As Long
Dim findcellKV As Variant

Dim cl As Range
Dim shpOval As Shape
Dim Counter As Integer

'set x equal to the id of your sheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(x)
BallSize = 8
FirstColumnKV = 24
FirstRowKV = 11

For Counter = FirstRowKV To 20
findcellKV = ws.Range(Counter, FirstColumnKV).Value
Set cl = ws.Range(Counter, FirstColumnKV)

clLeft = cl.Left
clTop = cl.Top
'I'm pretty sure that this wont work, but I cant test it, without your file. 
clOffsetV = (cl.Height / 2) - (BallSize / 2)
clOffsetH = (cl.Width / 2) - (BallSize / 2)

'Also not sure if this will work.
Set shpOval = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, clLeft + clOffsetH,clTop + clOffsetV, BallSize, BallSize)
shpOval.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(152, 52, 7)
shpOval.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(152, 52, 7)
shpOval.Line.Weight = 1

Next

End Sub
```

Also, as far as I can see, this will put a "Ball" in every cell you loop through. You would have to insert some kind of `if`-statement, where exactly you want your shapes.

Answer (score 0):

@Tom, thanks for your elaborate response. For some reason, though, the range defined as "Counter, FirstColumnKV" doesn't seem to work. Whereas when I set FirstColumnKV as "X" and use "FirstColumnKV & Counter" it does work fine. In any case, the original problem is solved now. The problem was the missing If-statement and some slight rearranging. I'll post the code as it is now for good measure:

```
Sub Bolletjes()

Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim Ws As Worksheet

Const BallSize = 8
Const FirstColumnKV = "X"
Const FirstRowKV = 11

Dim clLeft As Double
Dim clTop As Double
Dim clWidth As Double
Dim clHeight As Double

Dim findcellKV As Variant

Dim cl As Range
Dim shpOval As Shape
Dim Counter As Integer

Set Ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("C_Portfolio")

For Counter = FirstRowKV To 19
findcellKV = Ws.Range(FirstColumnKV & Counter).Value

If Format(Range(FirstColumnKV & Counter).Value) <> vbNullString Then
Set cl = Range(findcellKV)
clLeft = cl.Left
clTop = cl.Top
clOffsetV = cl.Height / 2 - BallSize / 2
clOffsetH = cl.Width / 2 - BallSize / 2

Set shpOval = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, clLeft + clOffsetH, clTop + clOffsetV, BallSize, BallSize)
shpOval.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(152, 52, 7)
shpOval.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(152, 52, 7)
shpOval.Line.Weight = 1

End If

Next

End Sub
```